# How to convert continuous variable to discrete in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I  have a variable which encodes group ID:

```
d <- data.frame(group = c(0,1,0,2,1,3,2,0,1,2), x=c(1.2,2.3,3.2,2.1,1.3,1.5,2.3,0.4,1.3,1.7))
```

When I try to use it in ggplot2 for making boxplots I get an error

> Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

At attempt to render data. Then I manually change at least one group ID in data to text everything works OK.

**So, my question is:** is where some easy way to change continuous variable, containing finite number of variants to discrete?

Comment: Could you provide the code you have used for `boxplot`?

Comment: `floor(data)`, `ceil(data)`, `round(data)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this:

```
ggplot(d) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(group), x))
```

gives the following plot

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since you're providing the `group` variable with a numeric vector, this is understood as a continuous variable. You need to convert it to a categorical variable. Try the following:

```
d <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c(0,1,0,2,1,3,2,0,1,2)), x=c(1.2,2.3,3.2,2.1,1.3,1.5,2.3,0.4,1.3,1.7))
```

The `as.factor` function will convert the numeric vector you provided for the groups to a discrete variable.